# How to get the most similar match using BERT from a pandas column to an input string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find the most similar match in a column of a pandas dataframe to an input string that is not in English (Swedish). This is what I have tried. I have encoded both my input string and the texts in the pandas' column and then I tried to calculate cosine similairy between the two:

```
# Load the pre-trained BERT model for Swedish language
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("KBLab/sentence-bert-swedish-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("KBLab/sentence-bert-swedish-cased")

def find_similar(input_text, column_name, df):
    # Encode the input text and the text in the column
    encoded_input = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors='pt', truncation=True)
    input_ids = encoded_input[0]
    column_text = df[column_name].tolist()
    column_ids = [tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors='pt') for text in column_text]

    # Calculate the similarity score between the input text and each text in the column
    with torch.no_grad():
        input_embeddings = model(encoded_input).last_hidden_state
        column_embeddings = [model(column_id).last_hidden_state for column_id in column_ids]
        similarity_scores = [cosine_similarity(input_embeddings, embedding).item() for embedding in column_embeddings]
    
    # Find the index of the text with the highest similarity score
    max_index = similarity_scores.index(max(similarity_scores))
    
    # Return the most similar text
    return column_text[max_index]

input_text = test
column_name = "DESC"
most_similar_text = find_similar(input_text, column_name, df)
print(most_similar_text)
```

But this throws the `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [49], line 3
      1 input_text = test
      2 column_name = "DESC"
----> 3 most_similar_text = find_similar(input_text, column_name, df)
      4 print(most_similar_text)

Cell In [48], line 12, in find_similar(input_text, column_name, df)
     10     input_embeddings = model(encoded_input).last_hidden_state
     11     column_embeddings = [model(column_id).last_hidden_state for column_id in column_ids]
---> 12     similarity_scores = [cosine_similarity(input_embeddings, embedding).item() for embedding in column_embeddings]
     14 # Find the index of the text with the highest similarity score
     15 max_index = similarity_scores.index(max(similarity_scores))

Cell In [48], line 12, in <listcomp>(.0)
     10     input_embeddings = model(encoded_input).last_hidden_state
     11     column_embeddings = [model(column_id).last_hidden_state for column_id in column_ids]
---> 12     similarity_scores = [cosine_similarity(input_embeddings, embedding).item() for embedding in column_embeddings]
     14 # Find the index of the text with the highest similarity score
     15 max_index = similarity_scores.index(max(similarity_scores))

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (19) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Is there a way to resolve this?